# Update From In MongoDb Driver c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do I do the following in MongoDB Driver?

```
Update MyTable1 
set MyTable1.ColumnA = MyTable2.ColumnZ
from MyTable1
inner join MyTable2
    on MyTable2.PrimaryKeyValue = MyTable1.ForeignKeyValue
Where MyTable1.ColumnA is null;
```

For example, a MongoDb Driver select equivalent query would look like this:

```
            IMongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://host:port/");
            IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("InventoryPOS");
            IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Collection1");
            
            // Created with Studio 3T, the IDE for MongoDB - https://studio3t.com/
            
            var options = new AggregateOptions() {
                AllowDiskUse = true
            };
            
            PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
            {
                new BsonDocument("$project", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("_id", 0)
                        .Add("Collection1", "$$ROOT")), 
                new BsonDocument("$lookup", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("localField", "Collection1.ForeignKeyId_Property")
                        .Add("from", "Collection2")
                        .Add("foreignField", "PrimaryKeyId_Property")
                        .Add("as", "Collection2")), 
                new BsonDocument("$unwind", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("path", "$Collection2")
                        .Add("preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", new BsonBoolean(false))), 
                new BsonDocument("$project", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("Collection1.PropertyA", "$Collection1.PropertyA")
                        .Add("Collection2.PropertyZ", "$Collection2.PropertyZ")
                        .Add("_id", 0))
            };
```

I'm looking for a way to run an update using MongoDb Driver, c# where I can use a query like I have above to set "Collection1.PropertyA" to the value of "Collection2.PropertyZ"

Does that help explain what I'm asking for help with?

Comment: Do you want to use update operaion in C# with MongoDB driver?

Comment: Mongo has no sql, has no tables, has no join.

Comment: [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully better explain what I'm after.